# EMBER: Render div block only if component has yielded

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, hbs

I have the following hbs snippet:

```html
<div class='photo-viewer-control' local-class='leftbar'>
  {{yield to='leftbar'}}
</div>
```

I am consuming the leftbar component in:

```
<Viewer>
  <:leftbar>
    <Infos
      @image={{this.currentImage}}
    />
  </:leftbar>
</Viewer>
```

I want to render the div only if `leftbar` has yielded.

I already tried the following:

```html
{{#if (has-block 'leftbar')}}
  <div class='photo-viewer-control' local-class='leftbar'>
    {{yield to='leftbar'}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

I added the `has-block` but the div is still rendering when there is no `leftbar`.

Comment: can you add the snippet for how you're consuming this component? thanks!

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli i added the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close!

To avoid rendering a `:leftbar`, omit the block:

```
<Viewer>
  no left bar will be rendered
</Viewer>
```

here is a [demo of how this works](https://limber.glimdown.com/edit?c=MQAgMglgtgRgpgJxAUQCYQC4HsEChfCgDqmAFiAFICGAblQMoDGCEADhvo1qnCAGZwAdo14YqAcwDOIRlUEh4IAK6S4qENhDoEcRhgA2ATxA7BPJFyissgoRkkAaXFWkB3OPv0gXJoeY2kvFw8IJKCbKxwGAG8%2BhA0QdyJUHDSfAhYUAB0%2BADy7BA2kgBc%2BAC0IAAGcQmVIBUA%2Bqbm0hDyrPpUIg24FdXxvKw6NBBwrnVNfoit7Z0iDiAdXW3iMaFYSggi3nwYiGs1vM2IPX2Hi8OjrgoeWOMgk2bTIG2Lc3ALS4wrBwO%2BT0h4Po7mtJBstnAergADykBAAegAfPhKqjxAAraTnIZwEZjXDQawIaIAYUy1lsgmi6UyIAA5AABcRxKApBGWCl2OkAbgJVhw0QA3hoEF0ANZqEAAX34GSg9KZLLZ8IwosYYpWPL5RKFIBs0tltMZcFgiHhUG4ED4owQWtwXEEkmiADUrvsALwgaF7KydPbIkAgQWCwyjfSoKVS-CB4PAK0gAAUpBcZRgwPV9P0cF2MCotoAlJHcIHA9D0DQAyWYyGw%2BpsO6AERZnN5htFqvQ%2BHlyvB%2BFWoudn1Lf28mFDv1wSvQ11jRCV0vFZsYXMIeclpcrmQ2PZU4slzuL7PLvNT%2BEz9yr6Ne89zveBwRYEAbvNbql2Pedm%2BXwcm4eT3CopUuBAA&format=glimdown)

```
const Viewer = <template>
  {{yield}}

  {{#if (has-block 'leftbar')}}
    <div>
      {{yield to="leftbar"}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>;

<template>
  <Viewer>
    <:leftbar>
      leftbar content
    </:leftbar>
  </Viewer>

  <Viewer>
    no leftbar content
  </Viewer>
</template>
```

(this demo uses the new "gjs" format -- tutorial here, if unfamiliar: https://tutorial.glimdown.com )